# It is grammatically correct to have an adverb both before and after a verb?

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

I was proofreading a paper for a friend and came upon this sentence:

> Their doctors did not have the knowledge of what was truly happening physically.

Is it grammatically correct to have an adverb such as "truly" before a verb, and another adverb such as "physically" after the same verb? Do they both need to be on the same side?

Comment: Short answer: It's fine. "They were not really playing well".

Comment: They never ran faster.

Comment: He usually pays monthly. _And even_ He truly answered truly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence is fine. In fact, it is customary to put an "adverb of manner" after the noun. Adverbs of manner are adverbs that indicate HOW something happens. This article goes into details what they are and how to use them: [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode75/languagepoint.shtml#:%7E:text=It%20is%20possible%20to%20place,places%20emphasis%20on%20the%20adverb.&text=But%20some%20adverbs%20are%20always,%2C%20badly%2C%20hard%2C%20fast.)